# Cannot download an app on my Android tablet

Tags: tablet

I thought if I deleted the internal SD card info it would help and I have downloaded apps since but the Facebook messenger app says application cannot be installed in the default installation location error 20 troubleshoot and I have plenty of storage space.

Comment: How did you download and install? Are you talking about Google Play Store here? Are you also seeing an error telling you there's "insufficient storage available"? Note that it doesn't matter if you had 1 TB free space on your SD card if the internal storage is filled up (see our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for details).

Comment: Thank you but what happened was I deleted all internal SD card info anthem it popped the empty card loose it said to mount the card so I figured zi would just pop it back in and now I have a lot more storage ang the play store is working but I also had to disable the play store and then enable it again to which helped but thank you do much for trying to he

Comment: Glad you were able to solve your issue, Sharon! May I suggest you answer your own question (and then "accept" the answer), so other "seekers" can see it has a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had deleted everything from the SD card, and it popped out asking me to mount the card and put a new one in. I just put in the old empty card and then I disabled play store and enabled it. After that I moved so many apps to the card I have a lot of space and the play store works perfect again – but this took me 4 hours to figure out! Hope this can help someone else oneday!